# Office Add-in show warning - unsupported features by its add-in catalog (SharePoint App Catalog)

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, office365-apps

I'm trying to deploy a Word Add-in.

1. I've deployed the backend on an onpremises server to IIS. And I've checked it's accessible.
2. I've created an app catalog in Office365 and uploaded the manifest file to the catalog. The catalog shows that the Add-in is valid
3. I've added the Office365 app catalog to the trusted catalog sites
4. I can add the app, I see that it shows part of my design, but it gives an info text and the Add-in doesn't work:

Info text:

> ADD-IN INFORMATION
>
> This Add-in uses features not supported by its add-in catalog.

The manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:ce44715c-8c4e-446b-879c-ea9ebe0f09c8-->
<OfficeApp 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
          xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides"
          xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>e4a1b6ce-9333-44b5-bf03-59435dbf66ac</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Name</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Name" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Name"/>

  <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button32x32.png" />

  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->
  
  <!--Begin TaskPane Mode integration. This section is used if there are no VersionOverrides or if the Office client version does not support add-in commands. -->
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <!-- End TaskPane Mode integration.  -->

  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>

  <!-- Begin Add-in Commands Mode integration. -->
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    
    <!-- The Hosts node is required. -->
    <Hosts>
      <!-- Each host can have a different set of commands. -->
      <!-- Excel host is Workbook, Word host is Document, and PowerPoint host is Presentation. -->
      <!-- Make sure the hosts you override match the hosts declared in the top section of the manifest. -->
      <Host xsi:type="Document">
        <!-- Form factor. Currently only DesktopFormFactor is supported. -->
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!--"This code enables a customizable message to be displayed when the add-in is loaded successfully upon individual install."-->
          <GetStarted>
            <!-- Title of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a ShortString resource -->
            <Title resid="Name.GetStarted.Title"/>

            <!-- Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
            <Description resid="Name.GetStarted.Description"/>

            <!-- Point to a url resource which details how the add-in should be used. -->
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="Name.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <!-- Function file is a HTML page that includes the JavaScript where functions for ExecuteAction will be called. 
            Think of the FunctionFile as the code behind ExecuteFunction. -->
          <FunctionFile resid="Name.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" />

          <!-- PrimaryCommandSurface is the main Office Ribbon. -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use OfficeTab to extend an existing Tab. Use CustomTab to create a new tab. -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <!-- Ensure you provide a unique id for the group. Recommendation for any IDs is to namespace using your company name. -->
              <Group id="Name.Group1">
                <!-- Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                <Label resid="Name.Group1Label" />
                <!-- Icons. Required sizes 16,32,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX. -->
                <!-- Use PNG icons. All URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS. -->
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Name.tpicon_16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Name.tpicon_32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Name.tpicon_80x80" />
                </Icon>

                <!-- Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu". -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Name.TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="Name.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                    <Title resid="Name.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
                    <Description resid="Name.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Name.tpicon_16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Name.tpicon_32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Name.tpicon_80x80" />
                  </Icon>

                  <!-- This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFunction or ShowTaskpane. -->
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <!-- Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane. -->
                    <SourceLocation resid="Name.Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    
    <!-- You can use resources across hosts and form factors. -->
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Name.tpicon_16x16" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/App_Data/img/Name_logo_16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Name.tpicon_32x32" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/App_Data/img/Name_logo_32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Name.tpicon_80x80" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button80x80.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Name.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Functions/FunctionFile.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Name.Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/" />
        <bt:Url id="Name.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <!-- ShortStrings max characters==125. -->
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Name.TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Templates" />
        <bt:String id="Name.Group1Label" DefaultValue="Name" />
        <bt:String id="Name.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Name templates" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <!-- LongStrings max characters==250. -->
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="Name.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="Name.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started." />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
  <!-- End Add-in Commands Mode integration. -->

</OfficeApp>
```

I'm assuming it's the manifest file that's causing this. I'm not sure what's wrong with this file, as I followed the default tutorials and file -> new project in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add-in command annotations are not supported in the SharePoint add-in Catalog. The only deployment option that will support add-in commands in the short term (other than the store) is our new Office 365 Centralized Deployment Tool, who is in preview right now. Check out the documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Deploy-Office-Add-ins-in-the-Office-365-admin-center-preview-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE).  (Note that the preview is for now only available on these geographies: US,CA,GB,AU,Ireland and NZ. )

That said, you can still use the SP-Based catalog, but you will need to remove the add-in commands annotations from the manifest (all the overrides), and users will need to go to the insertion dialog to insert your add-in.

Please make sure to [consult this page for all the deployment options](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/publish) for add-ins and important remarks about each of them.

Comment: Thanks. Will remove the Add-in command annotations for now and hope that the Office 365 Centralized Deployment Tool will become available soon.

Comment: @"Juan Balmori" When you say "Add-in Command annotations" what do you mean by that? Looking for what we need to remove for it to comply. We've just deployed an addin via the sharepoint App catalog and are getting the same error from the Excel local App when opening: "This Add-in uses features not supported by its add-in catalog.". Our Add-in is a Excel Taskpane App with SharedRuntime. On the Excel web version we don't have any errors.